# Drupal : Access values in field-collection with twig

Tags: symfony, object, drupal, twig, drupal-8

In my Drupal project I'm unable to access values of a field-collection. I can output all values by using:

```
{{ item.content }}
```

But I'm not able to get deeper nested values, which are objects.

For example I would like to get the value «field_interpret».

[image]

This things don't work:

```
{{ item.content['#field_collection_item'] }}
{{ item.content.#field_collection_item }}
{{ item.content.field_collection_item }}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of searching and testing I ended up with a plain old and dirty sql-query which I included in the preprocess_field function.

My problem was, that I don't found a way to access the elements in a field-collection and I had to make some calculation based on the field values.